# Convert multidimensional array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array with up to [32][32] entries.
And I'd like to convert it from something like this:

```
[
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "player1"],
    [null, null, null, null, null, "player2"]
]
```

to

```
{
  "6": {"10":"player1"},
  "7": {"5":"player2"}
}
```

So this would be my array:

```
var gameField = [];
gameField[6] = [];
gameField[6][10] = "player1";
gameField[7] = [];
gameField[7][5] = "player2";
```

Now I tried to use this:

```
var obj = {}
obj = Object.assign({},gameField);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

but it only worked for the outer array, the inner arrays were not affected:

```
{
    "6": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "player1"],
    "7": [null, null, null, null, null, "player2"]
}
```

What would be the shortest way to do this properly?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This seems like a very bad structure, before *and* after. Dynamic object keys are mostly hard to use. Why don't you use something cleaner like for example `[ {player:'player1', numberOfX:10}, {player:'player2', numberOfX:5} ]`.

Comment: The structure is a bit more complicated in reality. There is more than just players.  What I want to achive is to simply convert a 2d array into an object that uses the array indexes as keys. So that I can get rid of all the null values of the array.

Comment: technically it is [10] would be index = 11

Comment: @Forivin If your structure is even more complicated, my point is even more appropriate.

Comment: Well it's complicated in a way that it would be significantly more complicated to parse it when done the way you suggest it. Also, more importantly: The mentioned array structure is already deeply implemented into my project. I just want to reduce the array size by converting it to an object before i send it form the server to a client.

Comment: A sample code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xm8pjp6j/). I'm still unable to properly understand the requirement, but hope this helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over the items in the array and then recurse if the located item is itself an array (check using `Array.isArray`)

```
function populateFromArray(array) {
  var output = {};
  array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (!item) return;
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      output[index] = populateFromArray(item);
    } else {
      output[index] = item;
    }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(populateFromArray(input));
```

This results in:

```
[object Object] {
  6: [object Object] {
    10: "player1"
  },
  7: [object Object] {
    5: "player2"
  }
}
```

See a [working jsBin](https://jsbin.com/durayedefa/1/edit?js,console)

Note: you can certainly do this in less code but less code is not always better!

Comment: Nice, it works. Can you elaborate a bit on the "less code" thingy?

Comment: If you see the answer from @redu then you have a perfect example.  This is much less code but - in my opinion - is much harder to understand.

Comment: The good thing about your code is that is doesn't break if you place objects instead of strings in the original array.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` seems ideal for this. You may do as follows;

```js
var dataArr = [null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"Player1"],[null,null,null,null,null,"player2"]],
    dataObj = dataArr.reduce((p,c,i) => (Array.isArray(c) && (p[i] = {[c.length-1]:c[c.length-1]}),p),{});
console.log(dataObj);
```

Comment: Though if I use an object like `{id:0,name:'Player1'}` instead of "player1", I cannot access the property anymore after the conversion.

Comment: @Forivin... Sorry there was an extra set of brackets that i overlooked which was resulting an array `["player1"]` instead of a string `"player1"`. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this recursive function, using ES6 code:

```js
var data = [null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"player1"],[null,null,null,null,null,"player2"]];

function convert(data) {
    return Array.isArray(data)
        ? data.reduce( (obj, el, i) => (el && (obj[i] = convert(el)), obj), {} )
        : data;
}

var obj = convert(data);

console.log(obj);
```

This will also work when your input array is nested deeper than 2 levels. It does not require the non-null elements to be at the end of their (sub-)array, nor that there is only one non-null element per (sub-)array.